# How to plot a function using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot the function:

11.34×10^(-9) t^4 + 29.92 t - 833.5 = 0

using the TikZ graphing package.  I know this should be easy but I am struggling with some syntax issues resolving the exponents.  What is the proper syntax for that equation in TikZ (or the most appropriate way to render)?

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false,xlabel=Temperature degrees C,
    ylabel=Power (W),xmin=-2000,ymin=-20000]
    \addplot[domain=0:150, blue, ultra thick,smooth]
    {(11.34*10^-9)*x^4+29.92*x+833.5};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you make your code compilable? And can you tell us what is unsatisfactory about the output? We have no way of knowing which equation you are trying to typeset with that code.

Comment: I think so.  This is what I have:

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false,xlabel=Temperature degrees C, ylabel=Power (W),xmin=-2000,ymin=-20000]
\addplot[domain=0:150, blue, ultra thick,smooth] {(11.34*10^-9)*x^4+29.92*x+833.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: Sorry, that did not paste correctly.

Comment: You can edit your question using the `edit` link at bottom left of it.

Comment: Can I paste a picture into this thread?

Comment: You can paste a picture into your question if you edit it.

Comment: I've tried to complete your code? Is that what you have?

Comment: I have the picture but can't get it pasted in this thread.

Comment: @JohnKormylo How do you know it should be `e`?

Comment: You can upload it when you edit your post. Click on the picture symbol.

Comment: The tikz code stops plotting once the y-vale reaches 0.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It was not me who claimed otherwise.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I asked how you knew it should be `e`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to know what you want to do. However, note that you are plotting much less than you are axising, so to speak. If you increase the domain, for example, you get this:

[image: more plot]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false,xlabel=Temperature degrees C,
    ylabel=Power (W),xmin=-2000,ymin=-20000]
    \addplot[domain=-2000:150, blue, ultra thick,smooth]
    {(11.34*10^-9)*x^4+29.92*x+833.5};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I still haven't found the add picture button but I think what you have done is really close.  I am trying to highlight the solutions at -1391 and at 27.8.

Comment: Identifying the x-intercepts is what I am trying to highlight.

Comment: As an applied mathematician, I should mention that `(11.34e-9*x*x*x+29.92)*x+833.5` is the recomended form.